# Auth in Kohana 3.2 doesn't login users after migration to another hosting

Tags: php, authentication, kohana-3.2

After a migration to the new hosting, users can't login with correct data. All DataBase and auth settings were left the same (except new DB host, DB user name and password)

Here is the settings of auth.php:

```
return array(
    'driver'       => 'orm',
    'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
    'hash_key'     => '<my hash key>',
    'lifetime'     => Date::HOUR * 2,
    'session_type' => Session::$default,
    'session_key'  => 'auth_user',
);
```

Password values in table "users" are the same as i'm getting with the following code:

```
hash_hmac('sha256', 'password', '<my hash key>');
```

But `Auth::instance()->logged_in('<any advanced user role>')` returns FALSE everytime.

So what is wrong and what did i miss during migration?

PS: Kohana version is 3.2.2, all old cache files are cleared. Table "roles_users" contains "login" records for all users too.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Only thing I can think of that Date is not set properly, so the lifetime is not set.. You can try to write out the lifetime value?

Comment: Thnx for answer, Juan! But may you please sepcify which new value for "lifetime" is better? I changed it to simple numbers - no effect.

Comment: I've insvestigated logs and found several reasons to block login:
1) Unwriteable session path (in new place i made it via ini_set).
2) Deprecated using of preg_replace /e parameter (in enw place we have newest PHP).

So now i have nice clear logs, but login still doesn't work :-(

Comment: Check letter case stored in database and generated by hash function.